# "oppose" and "be opposed". What is the difference?

Tags: meaning, difference, word-meaning, verbs, word-difference

I have met real phrases with word "oppose" and combination "be opposed". And meaning of both looks similar. Is there actual difference between these two options?

Examples:

Lincoln was opposed to slavery.

John Kerry opposed this idea.

What is the difference?

Comment: The difference is whether the word was used as an adjective or a verb. Lincoln was opposed (**adjective**) to slavery. John Kerry opposed (**verb**) this idea.

Comment: Hi Andrey Epifantsev, welcome to the site!

Comment: If you oppose something or you you are opposed to something, there is no difference in meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Statement 1

> Lincoln was opposed to slavery

describes an attitude or belief.

Statement 2

> John Kerry opposed this idea.

describes an action.

I can be opposed to something - i.e. think it's wrong, believe it should be changed - without actually doing anything active to stop it - e.g. voting against it, protesting etc.

Comment: That would be a good answer if you had said "I can BE OPPOSED TO something...

Comment: Exactly. That's why in the last sentence of your answer, when you speak of ". . . without actually doing anything to stop it. . . ", you meant "be opposed to". But instead you said "oppose".

Comment: If I want to say that two terms are different from each other, do I say that "the x term opposes to the y term" ?

Answer (score 0):

The difference would be action or state of being verb. Really, in the first sentence, the verb is *was* + predicate adjective. In the second sentence, the verb is *opposed*. State of being verbs include: is, are, was, and were.

Comment: I left out *to be* and *being*.

Answer (score -1):

They have no difference in meaning, except word classes.

Definition of *oppose* by [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/oppose):

> **verb**
>   
> : to disagree with or disapprove of (something or someone)
>   
> : to compete against (someone) : to be an opponent of (someone)
>   
> : to try to stop or defeat (something)
>   
> *opposed (past)*

Definition of *opposed* by [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/opposed):

> **adjective**
>   
> : not agreeing with or approving of something or someone
>   
> : completely different

You can also try to [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+opposed) for the definition of *opposed* if you do not believe it has another form, which is **adjective**.

---

Hence, the first sentence was describing her opposition but the second sentence was trying to convey the message that John Kerry had opposed the idea.